# "Бета версия" или "бета-версия"

Tags: орфография, пробелы

Подскажите, как верно пишется?

Ведь мы точно опишем "бета-тестирование". Но почему-то тот же Google поправляет, что "бета версия". Раздельно, а не через дефис.

Comment: Поиск в Google тоже дает дефисное написание.

Answer (score 2):

бета-… - первая часть сложных слов, пишется через дефис, но: бетатрон, бетатронный, бетатронщик, бетаферон

См.: [Академический орфографический словарь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/lop/)